# Why is there an encoding error when scraping aliexpess in python?

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping

I am trying to sparse data about users who have left product reviews, here is my code:

```
from requests import Session

prod_link = 'https://aliexpress.ru/aer-jsonapi/review/v2/desktop/product/reviews? 
product_id=1005002273741565&_bx-v=2.5.3'

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'bx-ua': '226!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…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',
    'bx-umidtoken': 'T2gAlh4K7GYDUQtaLnLIXtKYXOGiPaDvGBeIYwulBA2EHcIU0wro2BkZHZY_QEsmwfI=',
    'bx-v': '2.5.3',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length': '110',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Cookie': 'xman_t=RXoRebOtb4ftBN2WbN9/rtiCGW2xzgK854ZgpklbQg8U52XU4v51zVSuvFTgzKuJ; xman_us_f=x_locale=ru_RU&x_l=0&acs_rt=85f8fdc656c74d6085f4fc3aaac93e75; ali_apache_id=33.22.68.84.1695627448340.419651.1; xman_f=XEAqNyHvF8X4o90zEMxeG0kMsrAO11gwwUDKM9JTbpGHHx1aprTSh5dsut/6MCKvxVuroWsB2oYBz1oh9ei+pZdGTSJ10JzF6BNm3E0LRN3W4PpcwiXyRg==; aep_usuc_f=b_locale=ru_RU&c_tp=KZT&region=KZ&site=rus&province=910800150000000000&city=910800150001000000; intl_common_forever=v4oQtMj6lIxIJlwWxKAjqOApaYASyWcwHQ29Hu0DmCJrL19+wFU4rQ==; JSE…5nId6dMaEk0kpxDmvnEf2ofEz4hNV3trVintT2uNTnS47ZuxJ98Vq0TRkw7FOi_4uq5Ry6QfRZ0m6NSEzDJ2JkitT4H88nSo-LDoKvmYDy4FEYDfbecLN2l09ySXDoUU8TDoKvmYTFuvMsMuU-G7L6tBxqBaNrTdHPppuNLlceNettTxZ4EAnWPI-609OltnxH-aZ4Yq6KtF_5zOluvev91.; xlly_s=1; _ga=GA1.2.591272089.1695627122; _gid=GA1.2.1381013730.1695627122; tmr_lvid=3a843f798d5a1894752cf98b05e669de; tmr_lvidTS=1695627122617; tmr_detect=0%7C1695627440950; _fbp=fb.1.1695627127724.1352887578; ae_ru_pp_v=1.0.2; a_t_info={"name":"","id":"b32f324f-ed30-43ff-869c-5ae402d203ee"}',
    'Host': 'aliexpress.ru',
    'Origin': 'https://aliexpress.ru',
    'Referer': 'https://aliexpress.ru/item/1005002273741565.html?sku_id=12000019864909870&spm=a2g2w.productlist.search_results.13.7ce14aa67IRu36',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode':'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
    'TE': 'trailers',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/117.0'
}

def main():
    s = Session()
    s.headers.update(headers)

    response = s.post(prod_link)
    print(response.status_code)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I put everything in the headers as on the site that is required for this request. But it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\aliexpress\reviews_parse\main.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\aliexpress\reviews_parse\main.py", line 31, in main
    response = s.post(prod_link)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\aliexpress\reviews_parse\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 637, in post
    return self.request("POST", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\aliexpress\reviews_parse\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\aliexpress\reviews_parse\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\aliexpress\reviews_parse\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\aliexpress\reviews_parse\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\aliexpress\reviews_parse\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 496, in _make_request
    conn.request(
  File "E:\aliexpress\reviews_parse\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 394, in request
    self.putheader(header, value)
  File "E:\aliexpress\reviews_parse\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 308, in putheader
    super().putheader(header, *values)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 1259, in putheader
    values[i] = one_value.encode('latin-1')
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2026' in position 512: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Who has experience in parsing aliexpress? Can you please tell me what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\u2026` is the `…` symbol. Your header constants indeed include this symbol which is certainly a copy-paste error.

(The actual error is because `requests` converts header value to latin1 and `…` can't be encoded in latin1 but that's not something you should do anything about.)